# Auto enrollment process in Apple Wallet

Tags: ios, wallet, passkit

I am generating Loyalty card for Apple Wallet using Apple Pay API. Flow as below :

1. Customer receive SMS contains a hyperlink.
2. Customer taps on the link in SMS. User will be redirected to a page and
   download empty wallet loyalty card.
3. Upon download customer information Personal information must pre-populates
   from the phone before storing loyalty card in Wallet.

I completed step 1,2 but I am not able to figure it out how to fetch the user information from his phone during card installation.[image]

Comment: Step 3 is a private API that requires your Pass Certificate to be whitelisted by Apple.  You will need to contact the Apple Pay team to move forward.

Comment: even I am not using any NFC features ?

Comment: Yes - unfortunately, this functionality is only available for NFC passes.

Answer (score 0):

Getting access to the users information from the device when they download their pass in order to update it isn't possible.

You would have to create a online form and autofill the users information *before* the creating the users pass. You could generate the pass after they fill in the form and bounce to a page to download it.

See our solution at [PassNinja.com](http://passninja.com/), we will be releasing an API to create and distribute NFC enabled wallet passes on the fly.

Disclosure: I work for [Flomio](https://flomio.com/), the company behind PassNinja.